# cakePHP - Slug with array of named arguments

Tags: cakephp

I am abit stuck try to figure out how I can use slug on a URL with an array of named arguments:

The URL is as follows: `/controller/action/param:1-Slug1/param:2-Slug2/param:3-Slug3`

This gives me the following the named params array in the request object:

```
[named] => Array
        (
            [param] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1-Slug1
                    [1] => 2-Slug2
                    [2] => 3-Slug3
                )

        )
```

How do I configure the route to take the slug into consideration? Such that the output is:

```
[named] => Array
            (
                [param] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1
                        [1] => 2
                        [2] => 3
                    )

            )
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't need that `[0], [1]` stuff, by naming your parameters the same, you will automatically create an array. Thus change your url to

`/controller/action/param:1-Slug1/param:2-Slug2`

Your route for this will look like the following,

`Router::connect('/:controller/:action/*');`

By passing a star at the end the route will automatically pass through any extra params that you have added. This will allow you to pass as many parameters into the url that you want.

If you want to use a named parameter the route would look like this.

`Router::connect('/:controller/:action:/:slug', array(), array('slug' => '[a-z0-9-]+'));`

Which will match the slug against the regex in order to make a matching route. The regex allows any letters, numbers and hyphens.

Read more here, http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action

Comment: Hi David ... doesn't seem to be working ... I have set this route ... 

`Router::connect('/stats/trends/:slug', array('controller' => 'stats', 'action' => 'trends'), array('slug' => '[A-Za-z0-9-]+'));` and when accessing _/stats/trends/param:1-test_ ... I get the following data in the request params ... 

`[named] => Array
        (
            [param] => 1-test
        )`

Comment: Yes that's expected for your route.

Comment: I need to get rid of the -test part ... so I would need the output to be [named] => Array ( [param] => 1 )

Comment: Then don't put it in the url.

Comment: Hehe ... can't I instruct the route to consider it as slug?

Comment: I updated the question to better explain what I am trying to acheive

Comment: You mean more like `Router::connect('/:controller/:action/:id-:slug', array(), array('id'=>'[0-9]+','slug'=>'[a-z-]+'));`

Comment: doesn't seem to work for named parameters. That route would work for _/stats/trends/1-test_ .... but I need to pass multiple arguments like so ... _/stats/trends/brand:1-mybrand1/brand:2-mybrand2_

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27946/discussion-between-elgabbu-and-davidyell)